# SQL Server 2008 DBMail

Tags: sql, database, email

Could anyone help on the below stored procedure? I am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near '@profile_name'" SELECT distinct(EmailAddress)
>   as RECIPIENTS, @body = Replace(@bodypre, "$Approver", Forename) FROM
>   [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View]

in the query

```
SELECT distinct(EmailAddress) as RECIPIENTS,
      @body = Replace(@bodypre, "$Approver", Forename) 
FROM [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View]
```

which is part of this stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[test]
as
begin
DECLARE @subject VARCHAR(500)
Declare @bodypre varchar(5000)
DECLARE @ProgramName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @body VARCHAR(5000)
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(500)
declare @recipients VARCHAR(5000)
DECLARE @CurrentRec AS INT
DECLARE @RecCount AS INT
Declare @emailStop  as int
SET @CurrentRec = 1
SET @RecCount = 0

select @subject=EmailMessageSubject,
        @bodypre = EmailMessageBody,
        @emailStop = EmailStop_Flag
from STAS.dbo.MC_STAS_EmailMessage where TimeSheetStatusID = 3 

SELECT @RecCount = COUNT(EmailAddress) FROM [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View] 
if (@emailStop <> 1 AND @RecCount > 0)
    WHILE @RecCount >= @CurrentRec
    begin   
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    SELECT distinct(EmailAddress) as RECIPIENTS ,@body =Replace(@bodypre,"$Approver",Forename) from [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View]                    
        @profile_name = "STAS Email User",
        @recipients = @RECIPIENTS,
        @subject = @SUBJECT,
        @body = @body

    SET @CurrentRec = @CurrentRec + 1
end
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: **WHAT** error do you get? Please post the complete and detailed error message... we're not mind readers, nor can we see your screen....

Comment: Could anyone help on the below stored procedure? **I am getting error in the below query as "Incorrect syntax near '@profile_name'" SELECT distinct(EmailAddress) as RECIPIENTS, @body = Replace(@bodypre, "$Approver", Forename) FROM [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      EmailAddress as RECIPIENTS,
      @body = Replace(@bodypre, "$Approver", Forename) 
FROM [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View]
```

`DISTINCT` is not a function that you can call like you did - it's a SQL keyword.